# double() function in c++ or not?

Tags: c++, function

I hava following C++ code

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

#define pi 3.1415926

int n;
double* a,*b;
double Function(double);

double A(int j)
{
    double S=0;
    int ii;
    for (int i=-n;i<n+1;i++)
    {
        S=S+Function(2*pi*double(i)/(2*n+1))*cos(2*pi*double(j)*double(i)/(2*n+1));
    }
    if (j==0)
        return 1/double(2*n+1)*S;
    return 2/double(2*n+1)*S;
}
```

and  there isn't any declared function `double()`, and I looked for this function in math.h library and haven't found such. Can you explain what is it, is it a lambda expression or some delegate ?

Comment: `double(i)` is the intrinsic constructor of a `double` value. There's no function declared for it anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

`double(...)` could be thought of as another way of saying `(double)(...)`. Recall that when you have a class with a constructor that takes parameters you can write

```
MyClass(params)
```

and produce an instance of `MyClass`. C++ standard expanded the same syntax to primitive types as well. This syntax is shorter than the cast, because it does not require parentheses around `double` <sup>†</sup>.

Note: in the program above the explicit `double(i)` is unnecessary, because `pi` is already a `double`, and multiplying an `int` by a `double` produces a `double`.

<sup>†</sup> This may not work for primitive types with names that take multiple parts. For example, `unsigned int(12.4)` [will not compile under gcc](http://ideone.com/z0hbHp).

Comment: It's not exactly the same. and things start to go bad when you try to use `signed` and `unsigned` keywords. This will fail on GCC: `unsigned int(12.4)`

Comment: @YochaiTimmer Thanks for a good comment! I edited the answer to reflect it.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a function, it is a *constructor*.

```
double a(12.34);
```

constructs a new instance of the *double* type. In c++, all built-in types have implict constructors, I believe. They're not defined anywhere in particular, as they're a feature of the language.

For simple scalar type like *double*, it is more or less equivalent to

```
double a = 12.34;
```

(which is a copy assignment operation), but the two forms are definitely not the same for more complex types.

Answer (score 1):

It is a constructor of double data type.